# Linux version that is compatible with Berkeley XMLDB 2.5.16

Tags: oracle-xml-db, berkeley-db-xml

Is Berkeley DBXML 2.5.16 compatible with latest version of Red hat Linux?

Answer (score 0):

Not without some bugs. It's a ten year-old release, so you'll have to work your way through any issues related to compiler version changes. I was able to get all the way to the XQilla build before I ran into my first issue when attempting to build on Ubuntu Xenial.